# Term-by-term differentiation for the generating function of the Hermite polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, generating-functions, hermite-polynomials

Hermite polynomial $H_n$ is defined by
$$H_n(x) := \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}e^{x^2/2} \frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-x^2/2} $$
and its generating function is given by $F(t,x) := \exp{(tx-t^2/2)} $, i.e.
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^nH_n(x) = F(t,x). $$
Then, I want to differentiate above equation with respect to $t$ and $x$ (**interchanging summation and differentiation**) to derive the recurrence formula
$$H'_n(x) = H_{n-1}(x);\quad (n+1)H_{n+1}(x)=xH_n(x)-H_{n-1}(x) .$$

First, consider differentiating with respect to $x$. For this, how do we check the convergence of the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^nH'_n(x)$$
is uniform with resect to $x$ (on compact sets) ?

Second, differentiate with respect to $t$. How do we compute the radius of convergence of the power series or find a dominant series?